# Controls added dynamically won't show on form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm adding controls onto my form in location specified by their position in array. I've tried switching panels to buttons but  controls still aren't showing.

```
int[,] gamefield = new int[9, 8];
Panel[,] vis_gamefield = new Panel[9, 8];

private void Real_Move(int col) 
    {
        for (int i = 6; i > 0; i--)
        {
            gamefield[col, i] = 1;
            vis_gamefield[col, i] = new Panel();
            vis_gamefield[col, i].Name = "Panel" + moves;
            vis_gamefield[col, i].BackColor = Color.Red;
            vis_gamefield[col, i].Size = new Size(88, 88);
            vis_gamefield[col, i].Location = new Point(158 + 100 * (i - 1), 174 + 99 * (col - 1));
            vis_gamefield[col, i].Visible = true;
            vis_gamefield[col, i].BringToFront();
            vis_gamefield[col, i].Show();
            Win_Check(col, i);
            moves++;
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `I'm adding controls onto my form`  No, it looks like you forgot to add anything to the controls collection

Comment: You forgot to add the panels to the parent, consider `this.Controls.Add(vis_gamefield[col, i]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is kinda unclear how exactly do you add vis_gamefield to the forms Controls collection?

Do you have a line that says something like **`this.Controls.Add(vis_gamefield);`** in the Form constructor?

it should look something like below code

```
public Form1()         
{
    InitializeComponent(); 
    this.Controls.Add(vis_gamefield);
}
```